# Redis Rate Limiting fails under high load / concurrency

Tags: kotlin, redis

We had the following code in our repository but under high load / with a lot of concurrent requests the rate limiter sometimes returned `remaining = 0`.

```
eg. tenant = {
    userName = "foobar",
    rateLimit = 100
}

fun getRedisKey(user: String): String =
    "api_${user}_${LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)}" // eg. api_user_16:03:59

suspend fun tryAcquire(tenant: Tenant): AcquireRateLimitOutcome {
    val key = getRedisKey(user = tenant.userName)
    // Set rate limit value only if the key doesn't exist already (via 'nx()') and make it expiring after 1 sec (via 'ex(1)')
    redisConnection.set(key, "${tenant.rateLimit}", SetArgs.Builder.ex(1).nx())
    // Decrement rate limit value and retrieve current value
    val currentLimit = redisConnection.decr(key)!!.toInt()

    if (currentLimit >= 0) {
        return Success(limit = tenant.rateLimit, remaining = currentLimit)
    }

    return TooManyRequests(
        limit = tenant.rateLimit,
        remaining = 0,
        nrOfRequests = currentLimit.absoluteValue + tenant.rateLimit
    )
}
```

Can someone explain why it sometimes returned TooManyRequests. Although per second only about 10-20 requests where made?